# Migrating from MySQL to IBM Bluemix - which database service to use?

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud

How to migrate my whole database design + data on local server to IBM Bluemix Database Services? Which service should I use as equivalent to Apache MySQL (im using **WAMP** phpmyadmin on Local System).

Answer (score 1):

Use ClearDB, it is MySQL hosted as a service.  You can provision a ClearDB account through the Bluemix console and attach it to your app.  Once you have attached it to your app you can use the ClearDB console to load in your data.